# fcm push notification to mobile with topic messaging using C#

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an important requirement to push notification to more than 50000 mobile users (Android & IOS). We were implemented this by Topic Messaging. We created batch for every 998 users, and then push to the fcm using topic. But the delivery of push notification is inaccurate. Sometime, some devices get the notification message and some times, no devices. We were use only two topics, one for Android and other for IOS. Sending multiple batches(each batch contains 998 tokens) to the Same topic. Can you please share whats the issue behind this, or please share how to achieve the above scenario.

Batch Push

```
 public string pushBatchbasedonTopic(string Topic, List<string> RegisterIds)
            {
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log pushBatchbasedonTopic: ","");
                string topic = Topic;
                string str = null;
                try
                {
                    string senderId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCM_SENDER_ID"].ToString();
                    string applicationkey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCM_KEY"].ToString();
                    WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd");
                    tRequest.Method = "post";
                    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    tRequest.Timeout = 600000;

                    var dataser = new
                    {
                        to = topic,
                        registration_tokens = RegisterIds.ToArray()

                    };

                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var json = serializer.Serialize(dataser);
                    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationkey));
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
                    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log tRequest: ", tRequest.ToString());
                    using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                        {
                            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                                {
                                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                    str = sResponseFromServer;
                                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log sResponseFromServer: ", sResponseFromServer);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log TopicCreation: " + str, "");
                    return str;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    str = ex.Message;
                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log topic creation  error: " + ex.Message, "");
                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Stack Trace topic creation: " + ex.StackTrace, "");
                    _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n InnerException topic creation: " + ex.InnerException, "");
                    return str;
                }
            }
```

FCM Push

```
   public string pushusingFCMforBatchAndroidBasedOnOneTopic(string Id, string Condition, string Message, string Type, string count)
        {
            _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log pushusingFCMforBatchAndroidBasedOnOneTopic: ", "");
            string setcondition = Condition;
            //string deviceId = DeviceToken;
            string str = null;
            try
            {
                string senderId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCM_SENDER_ID"].ToString();
                string applicationkey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCM_KEY"].ToString();
                WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                tRequest.Timeout = 600000;

                var dataser = new
                {
                    //to = deviceId,
                    condition = setcondition,
                    data = new
                    {
                        Notification_Id = Id,
                        msg_type = Type,
                        Count = count,
                        sound = "Enabled",
                        body = Message,
                        badge = count
                    }
                    // count = 0,
                    //type = Type
                };

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = serializer.Serialize(dataser);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationkey));
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log tRequest: ", tRequest.ToString());
                using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                            {
                                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                str = sResponseFromServer;
                                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log sResponseFromServer: ", sResponseFromServer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log pushfcmandroid: " + str, "");
                return str;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                str = ex.Message;
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Log errorios: " + ex.Message, "");
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Stack Traceios: " + ex.StackTrace, "");
                _basemobile.WriteToLog("\n Inner Exceptionios: " + ex.InnerException, "");
                return str;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to include user ids as well? If a user subscribes to a topic, then FCM can figure out who to send the message to.

Comment: `Based on the publish/subscribe model, FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.`

Comment: @ZUNJAE     hey thanks for your response. Actually we are not subscribed to any topic. We are dynamically creating topics and pushing as batches. It works fine in our QA Environment where number of users are limited. But when comes to Production, number of users is more than 50000. The push notification is not delivered to any users. Should we keep any delay between the batch push and fcm push? or how to achieve this?